# Linq to Sql Group By without count

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, group-by

I have a linq to sql and have been researching how to use linq to sql to group your results.  I only see samples with count and sum in them.  My model is that each customer order has a variety of notes and could have multiple notes.  Right now it's listing all the customer orders and multiple times if it has multiple notes.

**How do I use group by in Linq to Sql without the sums/counts aggregate**

I have tried:

```
public IQueryable<object> getAllamcase()
    {
        try
        {
            var q = (from c in _context.Customer
                     join am in _context.table2 on c.id equals am.id
                     join ampn in _context.table3 on am.id equals ampn.id
                     join ay in _context.tabl4 on am.id equals ay.id
                     join oim in _context.table5 on am.id equals oim.id
                     group c.FileNum by new
                     {
                         FileNum = c.order,
                         assignmentdt = am.Assignment_DT,
                         oimname = oim.FullName,
                         notes = ampn.ProgressNotes,
                         years = ay.AMYear
                     }).AsQueryable();

            return q;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Could not get......", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

My results are look as multiple jsons

```
Customer  notes
1               notes 1
1               notes 2
1               notes 3
2               notes 1
2               notes 2
```

I just want it to return in one json  like

```
 Customer  notes
1              notes 1
               notes 2
               notes 3

2              notes 1
               notes 2
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do.  If you don't need the `.Count` property, don't use it.   Clarify what output you are getting and what you want instead.

Comment: @JamesCurran, I have updated my desired results.

Comment: You clearly haven't discovered navigation properties yet. Things like `Customer.Orders`, `Order.Notes`. They give you what you want right away. By the way, I hope these are not your real table names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but as I @GertArnold stated, if you want to load notes of customers you should use *Navigation properties*. Also, please look at [naming conventions](http://www.dofactory.com/reference/csharp-coding-standards). Your code will be much cleaner if you name variables, etc. correctly. But according to your question header, I can suggest you following. Imagine that you have *Note* class:

```
public class Note
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string NoteName { get; set; }
}
```

And you have list of Notes as following:

```
List<Note> notes = new List<Note>
{
    new Note { CustomerId = 1, NoteName = "note 1" },
    new Note { CustomerId = 1, NoteName = "note 2" },
    new Note { CustomerId = 1, NoteName = "note 3" },
    new Note { CustomerId = 1, NoteName = "note 4" },
    new Note { CustomerId = 2, NoteName = "note 1" },
    new Note { CustomerId = 2, NoteName = "note 2" },
    new Note { CustomerId = 3, NoteName = "note 1" },
};
```

If you want to get CustomerId-s and related notes from this list you can easyli achieve it by grouping them:

```
var result = notes
    .GroupBy(m => m.CustomerId)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        CustomerId = g.Key,
        Notes = g.Select(m => m.NoteName).ToList()
    });
```

The result will be:

```
CustomerId  ||  NoteName
1               note 1
                note 2
                note 3
                note 4
2               note 1
                note 2
3               note 1
```

I hope, it will help you.